# How to turn a home computer into an Internet server?

Tags: linux, security, routing, ftp

Assume the IP address of a home computer (Linux as OS) is known by all the clients. Files (of around 40KB) are to be sent to this computer from an Android device **over the Internet** and the computer (server) is expected to read these files. According to the content, the file is to be routed to another device **over the internet again**.

Specifications:

1. Up to 2500 files (100MB) are to be routed in a minute
2. The transfer should be secure.

---

The questions are:

1. Is it mandatory to use FTP protocol? Are there more convenient protocols or methods?
2. There are software to configure FTP servers like FileZilla. Is it possible to program FileZilla so that it executes the same code on each received file? If not any alternatives?
3. How do I grant the general security of the server and the data during transfer?
4. Assuming a dual-core, each core with two threads, how many transfers can be executed in parallel?
5. Is it practical to write the server code from scratch? What is the recommended language? Any clear and basic tutorial you would recommend?

**EDIT :** The question is closed due to the reason that it is not for a business environment. However, this system might be used for commercial/business purposes over the Internet if proven to bear with the demand.

Thank you.

Comment: THat's only one reason why it was closed. And I voted to keep it closed due to that rule: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: @Daniel I understand your concern. But there are ways to limit the borders of an open-ended questions. Anyone, who for any reason wants to answer, can define a specific situation and answer according to this specific case. You don't favor chatty questions but many times such talks gain people lots of insight, especially when the question is more broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to define the uses of a home server, it really depends on your needs and what kind of services you want to host on that computer, assuming that you know also how to basically configure a home network with a firewall ecc.

1. FTP is not recommended if not inside the house, not open to the internet, you could use also NFS and Samba but they're both unencrypted and suitable to use it open to the outside. SFTP is encrypted but also slower.
2. FileZilla has also a Server application, there are plenty of FTP and SFTP servers, it depends on what OS you plan to use to host it. Scripts on files can automate certain operations, you could use a good scripting language like Python to define some actions, and if you use Linux I recomend using rsync/rclone scripts over ssh for simple stuff, ansible to administrate multiple machines, or also Syncthing is really trending new stuff to see.
3. Security can be granted isolating the home network behind a Firewall and also using Updated OS and Applications, sending encrypted stuff, using a hosted home VPN to reach it from external places. PfSense is a good Firewall solution, as is WireGuard for a VPN.
4. Depends on the kind of operation that the computer has to do, for ex. encrypting and / or decrypting some files can hit hard 3/4 cores, streaming a video with transcoding hits the cpu and also the gpu. Really depends on the traffic / the network infrastructure you have (1Gigabit or 100M Home Lan). It requires testing it at full load and see if it can make it. Also a lot of Ram is necessary.
5. The server code should not be rewritten as there are vaild solutions and also entire Distros like FreeNAS or OpenMedia Vault, but if you need a Back-End to do some processing for you, sure you can write it from scratch, depends on how complex it may be, and if it's too simple you could rely on other solutions with some scripts doing the work.

Analyzing your problem you could use, Rsync to sync the files in real-time between the servers, you can use many flags to make it send only new/modified files + inotify to make it real-time between the 3 devices, there's lsyncd (thats rsync + inotify) directly embedded in the kernel.

For security you could use the above over SSH to place on layer of Encryption, as for the network you can use a hosted VPN on the middle Server with 2 Clients connecting to it. You could also use something more simpler as ZeroTier to unify devices over the Internet as it is a big "LAN", it's opensource, it supports all the OSs and they encrypt all the connections through their servers, I use it and they're trustable.

Good Luck, and stay safe!

Comment: Thank you. There are lots of concepts I am not familiar with and I don't know where to start. What I want to do is send 40KB files from Android device to another Android device over the Internet. Actually I want to hire a server in the future. The home server is just for test purposes and initial release of the App.

Comment: you could use a Shell on Android with the packets mentioned, I can sugest you Termux as it has almost all the Packets!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to give definitive answers without knowing more specifics about your requirements.  But in general:

1. ftp without some sort of tunneling is not secure and probably should be avoided. Maybe consider something like sftp or ftps.
2. Dunno.
3. Use an encrypted protocol for the transfer and follow all best practices.
4. Hard to answer without knowing what you're doing with the files after they've been received and more about the flow of the files coming in (for example: there's MUCH more processing overhead involved in opening 40 connections per second to receive 1 file per connection than opening 1 connection per second to receive 40 files).  You might try testing a prototype and look around for a second-hand server if the performance doesn't seem acceptable.
5. If you mean rewriting ftp/sftp/ftps/whatever code from scratch, absolutely not.  If you mean the backend code to handle the files after you've received them, sure - use whatever language that best fits the skills you have available.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. The thing is I need to transfer data between Android devices over the Internet and I am looking for a way to do it in a safe manner with minimum system requirements. The home server is for test purposes and early days of the App.